# You've got a little markup in your link text

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, moderator-tools

The link text in the flag summaries displayed when you visit questions and answers as a moderator are showing the closing anchor tag (`<\a>`). I don't think they should be:

[image: closing anchor tag appearing in link text]